# How use a function from algo.generic

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use from the Repl the algo.generic pow multifunction, in order to learn
clojure.
How can I use algo.generic from the Repl?

-I'm using lein repl.
-added [org.clojure/algo.generic "0.1.1"] at project.clj
-lein deps

```
=> (use 'clojure.algo.generic)
=> (pow 5 6)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: pow in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init6907113967558511638.clj:1:1)`
```

Thanks..

Comment: Have you added `algo.generic` to your dependencies?

Comment: yes, [org.clojure/algo.generic "0.1.1"] at project.clj

Comment: And not to be annoying, but ran `lein deps`? Then just a `use` macro will do it

Comment: yes I ran lein deps, @jozefg

Comment: @jozefg After run (use 'clojure.algo.generic) I can't find how call it => (pow 6 7)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: pow in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init6907113967558511638.clj:1:1)

Comment: Try `(use 'clojure.algo.generic.math-functions)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pow function is in the clojure.algo.generic.math-functions namespace, so you will need to "use" or "require" that namespace instead of the clojure.algo.generic